# Sufficient condition for swapping order of Lebesgue integration?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I want to swap the order of integration of a measurable function $f:X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ i.e.
$$
\int_A \int_B f(x,y) \mu(dx)\nu(dy) = \int_B \int_A f(x,y) \nu(dy)\mu(dx).
$$
for $A \subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$. If I know $f \in \mathcal{L}^1$ then I can use Fubini's Theorem. However would a sufficient condition be that simply
$$
\int_A \int_B \vert f(x,y) \vert \mu(dx)\nu(dy) < \infty ?
$$

Comment: isn't that the content of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem?

Comment: Isn't that only with $A=X$ and $B=Y$? So I am essentially asking if it is enough to just consider proper subsets?

Comment: yes, because then you're applying Fubini-Tonelli to $f\cdot \chi_{A\times B}$ instead of $f$.

Comment: Note Fubini's theorems require the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ there to be $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: If $f$ is measurable in $\mathscr{M}(\mu^*\otimes\nu^*)$ and its carrier $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: f(x,y)\neq0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite (with respect to $\mu^*\otimes\nu^*$), then $f\in L_1(\mu^*\otimes \nu^*)$ iff one of the iterated integrals $\int_X\Big(\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^*(dx)$ or $\int_Y\Big(\int_X|f(x,y)|\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)$ exists and are finite.  (To be continued...)

Comment: (continuation) When this happens, $$ \int_{X\times Y} f(x, y)\,\mu^*\otimes \nu^*(dx,dy)=\int_X\Big(\int_Yf(x,y)\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^*(dx)=\int_Y\Big(\int_Xf(x,y)\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)$$ and $$ \int_{X\times Y} |f(x, y)|\,\mu^*\otimes \nu^*(dx,dy)=\int_X\Big(\int_Y|f(x,y)|\,\nu^*(dy)\Big)\,\mu^* (dx)=\int_Y\Big(\int_X|f(x,y)|\,\mu^*(dx)\Big)\,\nu^*(dy)
$$ It also says that of either of the aforementioned iterated integrals of $|f|$ is infinite, then so will the other and in this case $\int_{X\times Y}|f| d(\mu^*\otimes \nu^*)=\infty$.